# How to style wordpress page without using too much HTML in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm fairly new to WordPress and I'm trying to figure out how to style things and create elements without adding too much HTML directly into the WYSIWYG editor. If I have a page that requires a three column layout with more intricate elements inside, I wouldn't want to use too much HTML and confuse a client who needs to edit content later. Are there any known techniques or tools to avoid writing too much code directly into the WP editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to write too much code, you should try a plugin like this one: [Shortcodes Ultimate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/).

It will add some buttons in your WYSIWYG (called TinyMCE) editor with some features like your columns.
A better solution is to write/build your own shortcodes but It's probably another subject.

here is some links if you want to get your hands dirty :)

- [Wordpress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)
- [WordPress Shortcodes Generator](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/)
- [Some simple exambles](http://aaron.jorb.in/blog/2010/02/wordpress-shortcodes-a-how-to-by-example/)

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Cool, I did checkout how to make custom shortcode. Very useful and not too hard, thanks for your advice.